# R 4.0.2 for windows: Trying to force the plot axis' to fit on x(-3 to 3) and y(1e-6 to 1)

Tags: r, plot, warnings, axis-labels

I've been trying to force R to make the plot axis' longer on both the x and y to compare it to a similar dataset. I've used both the `xlim` and `ylim` commands within the `plot()` function and the `axis()` function after the `plot` function, but neither has worked. After talking with a co-worker we found that I'm getting the following warnings with my script:

```
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
4: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  display list redraw incomplete
5: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
6: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : invalid graphics state
```

Attached below is a sample of the plot code and the subsequent result:

```
plot(x = q.ca[13:242], y = Censored.Alpha, log = "y", 
     xlab = "Z-Score", 
     main = "QQ Plot of DAC hours for Censored Alpha Radiation",
     ylab = expression(paste("DAC*hr for Alpha (", mu, "Ci)", sep = " "), 
     xlim = c(-4, 4), ylim = c(1e-6, 1)))
lines(q.ca, za)
abline(h = 1e-04, col = "red", lty = "dashed")
text(grconvertX(0.05, "npc"), grconvertY(0.9, "npc"), GSDA.c, pos = 4)
text(grconvertX(0.05, "npc"), grconvertY(0.95, "npc"), GMA.c, pos = 4)
```

Plot for the listed code above:
[image: Plot for the listed code above]

Can anyone help me with the errors? I'm unsure of where they're forming. More importantly, though, is anyone able to help me with the dimensions of the plot?

EDIT: I isolated the functions that generated the plot I was trying to create and for some reason now it's working  ¯_(ツ)_/¯, if anyone can help me decipher whats going on in the errors, that would be much appreciated, so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: Without your source data it's impossible to be sure, but the first place I'd look is `xlim`/`ylim`.  These *exclude* data from the undrrlying calculations which, as the doc says "[can produce unintended results](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html)".  From bitter experience, I've found it safer to use `coord_cartesian()` : this crops the plot but includes *all* data points, even those outside the plot limits.

Comment: The `ylab=` argument is lacking a right parenthesis, ")". You closed the `paste` function call but not the `expression` function call.